# How to implememt Paypal with my own shopping cart in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, paypal, webforms, paypal-adaptive-payments

I need help with code to reach PayPal with my shopping cart contents for an express checkout. Any help please....

Comment: Express Checkout and Adaptive Payments are separate products that you could integrate in different ways.  Are you just building a standard checkout system or are you doing something funky with splitting up payments in a particular way?

Comment: Hi Andrew, just building a standard checkout system. The only preference is for the cart contents to show on the PayPal invoice page. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/).  Specifically, you'll be using the following API calls:

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/?mark=setexpresscheckout)
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/?mark=getexpresscheckoutdetails)
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/?mark=doexpresscheckoutpayment)

In the SetExpressCheckout request is where you'll need to be sure to include itemized details so they show up in the PayPal checkout pages.  You also include the same itemized details in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment call to ensure those details are included in the final transaction details.

Comment: @Yomboy2006 Seems github has you covered: https://github.com/paypal/codesamples-dotnet